# Направление движения транспорта с помощью картинки Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot

Пишу телеграмм бота, который показывает движение транспорта на карте. Делаю это на питоне.

C картами телеграмм работает ограничено показывает только булавку, а мне нужно нарисовать и направление?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот пример данных, которые я получаю

```
1, 1, 39692550, 47219635, 12, 138, 344,
тип, номер_широта, долгота_скорость, курс, номер
```

предпоследний параметр показывает градусы по окружности.

Идея была такая, взять картинку со стрелкой и наклонять ее насколько надо.
И просто отправлять ее после карты ниже. Реализовал все с помощью библиотеки `PIL` , но получается плохо. После каждого поворота картинки, приходиться ее сохранять и под конец, она уже выглядит как набор пикселей.

Можете ли вы мне подсказать другие варианты?
Может все таки можно нанести на карту стрелку движения как в навигаторе. А может можно с помощью какой-нибудь математической библиотеки рисовать каждый раз компас с направлением и отправлять его как картинку?

Даже для юмора хотел реализовать все с помощью черепашки, но как создать изображение я так не разобрался.

Решил проблему используя google charts, передаю градусы по ссылке и гугл рисует сам картинку с направлением. Но все же вопрос в том,можно ли присылать локацию со стрелкой, а не с булавкой ?

Comment: "После каждого поворота картинки, приходиться ее сохранять и под конец, она уже выглядит как набор пикселей" интересный подход. А почему просто не показывать стрелку повернутую каждый раз?

Comment: А можно отрисовывать стрелку, основываясь на предыдущих координатах? допустим, предыдущее значение было (1:1), текущее (2:1) По двухмерной системе координат, стрелка должна быть направлена вверх

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Но все же вопрос в том,можно ли присылать локацию со стрелкой, а не с булавкой ?

Ответ на этот вопрос - **нет**. Локация - это точка на карте, как следует из [документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#location):

> **Location** This object represents a point on the map.

А метод **sendLocation** предназначен только для этого:

> Use this method to send point on the map.

Если Вам нужен какой-то специфичный функционал, то попробуйте использовать какие-то сторонние сервисы, генерирующие необходимое Вам изображение и посылайте его в виде фото.